# Ошибка "Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received" Flex

Tags: mysql, flash, apache-flex

Приложение flex. Работаю в adobe flash builder 4.5
Поставил соединение с базой mysql через php. При настройке всё прошло успешно. (база b сервер установлены пакетом денвера)
При запуске приложения вылезает ошибка:

```
Channel disconnected
Channel disconnected before an acknowledgement was received
```

Где могут быть причины данной ошибки?

Comment: При настройке типа возвращаемых данных получаю:

При вызове операции произошла ошибка. Проверьте входные данные или код сервера и повторите попытку вызова операции. 

Причина: 
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in ...

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in ...

Comment: Так может разные пользователи, есть в базе пользователь localhost ?

Comment: Проблема была решена. В коде была упущена строка коннекта к базе данных... /facepalm . Потратил 2 часа впустую.
В любом случае спасибо за помощь

Comment: Не за что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Проверить права и аккаунт зарегистрированный в базе.
- Посмотреть логи на стороне сервера.
- Это AIR или Web приложение?

Comment: Это AIR или Web приложение? - web

Comment: Если сервер и приложение запущены в разных доменах, например "http:\\localhost\" и "192.168.0.1:8080\" то вполне возможны сильные проблемы.